# IP address exists with no internet connection

Tags: networking, vmware

Im running ubuntu 14.04 with `vmware workstation 12` and its configured with `bridge` mode.

The problem I have is that on `ifconfig` I get IP address but I have no connection to the internet.

in the `settings -> network`, I have the `wired` field on the left but it shows only the mac address. if I enter the `options -> IPv4` Settings, the `method` field shows `Automatic (DHCP)`.

The file `/etc/network/interfaces` shows:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

I have red alot of posts but no post was helpful.

What is wrong here?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried ping and tracerout to see where the connection stops? Is the host OS blocking the connection?

Comment: Hi, traceroute is working, ping from ubuntu to the host working, ssh from the gost OS os working. but ping from the host to ubuntu is not working..